# Different Set.seed sample function results with same versions of R in different OS

Tags: r, random-seed

I have tried to use the sample function after setting seed, and run the code in a Mac computer and windows 10 computer respectively. However, there are different results when using the sample function even setting seed.

For Example:

In Mac Computer:

```
> set.seed(1)
> sample(100,3)
[1] 68 39 1
```

In Windows Computer:

```
> set.seed(1)
> sample(100,3)
[1] 27 37 57
```

However, the rnorm function has worked properly:

```
> set.seed(2)
> rnorm(3)
[1] -0.8969145  0.1848492  1.5878453
```

Is there anybody facing the same problem? R version is 4.1.1.

Comment: Maybe sett also the `kind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set also the `kind`:

```
set.seed(1, "Mersenne-Twister", sample.kind="Rounding")
sample(100,3)
#[1] 27 37 57

set.seed(1, "Mersenne-Twister", sample.kind="Rejection")
sample(100,3)
#[1] 68 39  1
```

Answer (score 2):

A likely cause of this problem is that one of the computers is still using the buggy `sample()` algorithm, because it was saved in a workspace and reloaded when you started R.

You can see which `sample()` algorithms are being used by running `RNGkind()`.
I see `[1] "Mersenne-Twister" "Inversion"        "Rejection"` , indicating that I'm using the Mersenne twister for uniforms, inversion for normals and rejection for discrete sampling.